# is there any documentation of which jquery-ui components jqGrid expects?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

having all of jqGrid and jquery-ui is starting to feel like bloat, but it's not entirely clear which portions of ui grid wants....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known, that all components of jqGrid need CSS file of jQuery UI with some corresponding images.

Since the version 3.6 of jqGrid there are an additional module of jqGrid [jQuery UI addons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods) which contains functions like `columnChooser`, `sortableRows`, `gridResize`, `gridDnD`. Moreover the `columnChooser` use an additional jQuery UI Multiselect Widget (see http://github.com/michael/multiselect, http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/ and http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/). One tested version of Multiselect Widget are included in the downloaded sources of jqGrid (ui.multiselect.css and ui.multiselect.js).

If you don't use any of the functions from [jQuery UI addons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods) listed above then it will be enough to include only CSS file of jQuery UI without calling of any js-files.